# Is it possible to have efficient timestamp ordered queries in spanner?

Tags: sql, google-cloud-spanner

I have followed this article https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/sharding-of-timestamp-ordered-data-in-cloud-spanner and created a somewhat similar schema just without companyID:

```
CREATE TABLE Foo (
  random_id       STRING(22) NOT NULL,
  shard_id              INT64 NOT NULL,
  timestamp_order    TIMESTAMP NOT NULL OPTIONS (allow_commit_timestamp=true),
) PRIMARY KEY(random_id);
CREATE INDEX OrderIndex ON Foo(shard_id, timestamp_order);
```

shard_id is a random number from 0 to 49. Then I am running a bunch of selects against it:

```
1: SELECT * FROM Foo@{FORCE_INDEX=OrderIndex} where shard_id=0 order by timestamp_order limit 1;
# this correctly scans 1 row

2: SELECT * FROM Foo@{FORCE_INDEX=OrderIndex} where shard_id<1 order by timestamp_order limit 1;
# this scans 192 rows

3: SELECT * FROM Foo@{FORCE_INDEX=OrderIndex} where shard_id BETWEEEN 1 AND 1 order by timestamp_order limit 1;
# this scans 185 rows

4: SELECT * FROM Foo@{FORCE_INDEX=OrderIndex} where shard_id BETWEEN 0 AND 1 order by timestamp_order limit 1;
# this scans 377 rows
```

I expected something like this:

```
Query #2 should scan 1 row
Query #3 should scan 1 row
Query #4 should scan 2 rows.
```

Question: what am I doing wrong here? Is it possible to have efficient timestamp ordered queries in spanner?

Comment: Add to your question what you did get.

Comment: @KaneKim The rows scanned in your case was a full table scan or a filter table scan.

Comment: @NirleyGupta it was an index scan (filter scan) - but all rows in the index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw the comment about an arbitrary LIMIT.  This was too long for a followup comment (not permitted) so I added another answer.

For an arbitrary LIMIT, a more complex query is required to get the highest efficiency.  Here is a template using the filter "shard_id < 1000" and LIMIT x.

The first side of the join will efficiently extract the qualifying shard_id values, very like the original query with LIMIT 1.  The second side of the join will go back to the table and fetch the top x rows for each shard_id.  The parent will then select the top x across all the qualifying shard_is values.  If there are many timestamps per shard_id then this will be very efficient.

```
SELECT ff.*
FROM
(
  SELECT shard_id
  FROM Foo@{FORCE_INDEX=OrderIndex, 
  GROUPBY_SCAN_OPTIMIZATION=true}
  WHERE shard_id < 1000
  GROUP BY shard_id
) shards
JOIN UNNEST(ARRAY
(
  SELECT AS STRUCT *
  FROM Foo@{FORCE_INDEX=OrderIndex} AS f
  WHERE f.shard_id = shards.shard_id
  ORDER BY timestamp_order
  LIMIT x
)) AS ff
ORDER BY ff.timestamp_order
LIMIT x;
```

Comment: This seems to work! I just had to add `SELECT AS STRUCT *
  FROM Foo@{FORCE_INDEX=OrderIndex}` otherwise it was complaining that array can select only 1 column.

Comment: BTW, Why can't one select directly from subquery? Why you need array/unnest combo?

Comment: It is because the subquery references the column from the other side of the join (shards.shard_id).  It is a bit cumbersome but once you are familiar with it, it's fine.

Comment: It seems to be emulating `LATERAL` because the standard `LATERAL` is not supported in the dialect.

Comment: I have noticed it needs extra back join in proportion to `[cardinality of shard_id] * [LIMIT]`. It can be reduced by SELECT only PK and explicit join with `Foo` table in outermost. https://github.com/gcpug/nouhau/blob/spanner/shard/spanner/note/shard/README.md (sorry, it is Japanese article)

Answer (score 4):

You can get efficient execution of this query using the HAVING MIN construct.

Rewritten #2:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (
    SELECT shard_id, ANY_VALUE(random_id HAVING MIN timestamp_order) AS random_id, MIN(timestamp_order) AS timestamp_order
    FROM Foo@{FORCE_INDEX=OrderIndex} 
    GROUP BY shard_id
    WHERE shard_id<1
    )
ORDER BY timestamp_order
LIMIT 1;
```

The efficiency will come from the inner subquery.  It should only scan one row for each shard_id and then choose the minimum from among those rows.  If you find that is not the case then there is a [hint](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/query-syntax#table-hints) that can force that behavior.

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (
    SELECT shard_id, ANY_VALUE(random_id HAVING MIN timestamp_order) AS random_id, MIN(timestamp_order) AS timestamp_order
    FROM Foo@{FORCE_INDEX=OrderIndex, GROUPBY_SCAN_OPTIMIZATION=true} 
    GROUP BY shard_id
    WHERE shard_id<1
    )
ORDER BY timestamp_order
LIMIT 1;
```

For the other queries, just replace the filter condition in the inner subquery.

Comment: It seems GROUPBY_SCAN_OPTIMIZATION=true did the trick! Without it it still was doing full scan. Trying if I can do same with other queries.

Comment: That solves LIMIT 1 issue, is there a way to do that with arbitrary limit?

Comment: I was able to do something close with UNION ALL fetching LIMIT number of rows per each shard then sorting combined result. It seems to work, but not very convenient still.

Comment: I added an additional answer for the arbitrary LIMIT case (it was too long to be permitted as a comment on the thread).

Comment: somewhat of a sidenote, while this query works, it seems the fact of having an index on the table slows down performance by 4x. Without this index I have got performance of updates (updating timestamp with commit_timestamp) close to 3500 on single node. WIth index performance is <800 writes/sec. While index understandably slows down performance I didn't expect this much. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: `HAVING` of `ANY_VALUE` seems undocumented.Please document it!

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate_functions?hl=en#any_value.
Document of ZetaSQL only have the description.
https://github.com/google/zetasql/blob/2020.04.1/docs/aggregate_functions.md#any_value

Comment: Adding a secondary index does unavoidably slow down writes.  The impact of additional indexes will be incremental over that first index.

Thanks, yes we noticed the documentation for HAVING MAX / MIN is missing - it is a fully supported feature and the documentation is on the way.

Comment: HAVING MAX / MIN seems now documented. https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/aggregate_functions?hl=en#any_value

Answer (score 0):

When you specify more than one shard id (or an expression that could yield more than one shard id), the theoretical result set at that point is no longer sorted by timestamp (whereas for a single shard it is), so it has to be resorted on timestamp (and every row has to be considered). A theoretical optimization when you specify a limit would be to take top N from each shard and merge, but it looks like that optimization is not in place.

You can implement this at the application layer by running a limit 1 query on each relevant shard in parallel and merging the results.

Comment: Yeah, I was surprised that this optimization isn't in place, while blog article does something that clearly needs that to be working (doing it like in article would trigger full table/index scan, which will kill the perf). Overall, this seems like a very cumbersome way to do it, I wonder if there is any better alternative (not to this specific query, but to have efficient global timestamp order).

Comment: The blog article is actually for getting a sort listed of all items in the index that match the query condition (no limit), so performance is not impacted there. Getting the top 1 or top N with a limit does have a performance impact (you scan the same rows you would if there was no limit), but Campbell's answer gives a performant way to do it.